# StackOverflowError: null in Android Studio | possible fix?

Tags: java, android, android-studio-2.0

I created a class in Android Studio and created a HashMap and initialized it with some pre-defined values, ever since then IDE displayed internal error occured. And right now, the class won't open in Android studio saying `StackOverflowError: null`. This is the static block I created :

```
static
{
    hm = new HashMap<>();
    hm.put("Arsenal VS Bournemouth,"M1X");
    hm.put("Arsenal VS Burnley,"M2X");
    hm.put("Arsenal VS Chelsea,"M3X");
    hm.put("Arsenal VS CrystalPalace,"M4X");
    hm.put("Arsenal VS Everton,"M5X");
    hm.put("Arsenal VS Hull,"M6X");
    hm.put("Arsenal VS Leicester,"M7X");
    hm.put("Arsenal VS Liverpool,"M8X");
    hm.put("Arsenal VS ManchesterCity,"M9X");
    hm.put("Arsenal VS ManchesterUnited,"M10X");
    hm.put("Arsenal VS Middlesbrough,"M11X");
    hm.put("Arsenal VS Southampton,"M12X");
    hm.put("Arsenal VS Stoke,"M13X");
    hm.put("Arsenal VS Sunderland,"M14X");
    hm.put("Arsenal VS Swansea,"M15X");
    hm.put("Arsenal VS Tottenham,"M16X");
    hm.put("Arsenal VS Watford,"M17X");
    hm.put("Arsenal VS WestBromWich,"M18X");
    hm.put("Arsenal VS WestHam,"M19X");
    hm.put("Bournemouth VS Arsenal,"M20X");
    hm.put("Bournemouth VS Burnley,"M21X");
    hm.put("Bournemouth VS Chelsea,"M22X");
    hm.put("Bournemouth VS CrystalPalace,"M23X");
    hm.put("Bournemouth VS Everton,"M24X");
    hm.put("Bournemouth VS Hull,"M25X");
    hm.put("Bournemouth VS Leicester,"M26X");
    hm.put("Bournemouth VS Liverpool,"M27X");
    hm.put("Bournemouth VS ManchesterCity,"M28X");
    hm.put("Bournemouth VS ManchesterUnited,"M29X");
    hm.put("Bournemouth VS Middlesbrough,"M30X");
    hm.put("Bournemouth VS Southampton,"M31X");
    hm.put("Bournemouth VS Stoke,"M32X");
    hm.put("Bournemouth VS Sunderland,"M33X");
    hm.put("Bournemouth VS Swansea,"M34X");
    hm.put("Bournemouth VS Tottenham,"M35X");
    hm.put("Bournemouth VS Watford,"M36X");
    hm.put("Bournemouth VS WestBromWich,"M37X");
    hm.put("Bournemouth VS WestHam,"M38X");
    hm.put("Burnley VS Arsenal,"M39X");
    hm.put("Burnley VS Bournemouth,"M40X");
    hm.put("Burnley VS Chelsea,"M41X");
    hm.put("Burnley VS CrystalPalace,"M42X");
    hm.put("Burnley VS Everton,"M43X");
    hm.put("Burnley VS Hull,"M44X");
    hm.put("Burnley VS Leicester,"M45X");
    hm.put("Burnley VS Liverpool,"M46X");
    hm.put("Burnley VS ManchesterCity,"M47X");
    hm.put("Burnley VS ManchesterUnited,"M48X");
    hm.put("Burnley VS Middlesbrough,"M49X");
    hm.put("Burnley VS Southampton,"M50X");
    hm.put("Burnley VS Stoke,"M51X");
    hm.put("Burnley VS Sunderland,"M52X");
    hm.put("Burnley VS Swansea,"M53X");
    hm.put("Burnley VS Tottenham,"M54X");
    hm.put("Burnley VS Watford,"M55X");
    hm.put("Burnley VS WestBromWich,"M56X");
    hm.put("Burnley VS WestHam,"M57X");
    hm.put("Chelsea VS Arsenal,"M58X");
    hm.put("Chelsea VS Bournemouth,"M59X");
    hm.put("Chelsea VS Burnley,"M60X");
    hm.put("Chelsea VS CrystalPalace,"M61X");
    hm.put("Chelsea VS Everton,"M62X");
    hm.put("Chelsea VS Hull,"M63X");
    hm.put("Chelsea VS Leicester,"M64X");
    hm.put("Chelsea VS Liverpool,"M65X");
    hm.put("Chelsea VS ManchesterCity,"M66X");
    hm.put("Chelsea VS ManchesterUnited,"M67X");
    hm.put("Chelsea VS Middlesbrough,"M68X");
    hm.put("Chelsea VS Southampton,"M69X");
    hm.put("Chelsea VS Stoke,"M70X");
    hm.put("Chelsea VS Sunderland,"M71X");
    hm.put("Chelsea VS Swansea,"M72X");
    hm.put("Chelsea VS Tottenham,"M73X");
    hm.put("Chelsea VS Watford,"M74X");
    hm.put("Chelsea VS WestBromWich,"M75X");
    hm.put("Chelsea VS WestHam,"M76X");
    hm.put("CrystalPalace VS Arsenal,"M77X");
    hm.put("CrystalPalace VS Bournemouth,"M78X");
    hm.put("CrystalPalace VS Burnley,"M79X");
    hm.put("CrystalPalace VS Chelsea,"M80X");
    hm.put("CrystalPalace VS Everton,"M81X");
    hm.put("CrystalPalace VS Hull,"M82X");
    hm.put("CrystalPalace VS Leicester,"M83X");
    hm.put("CrystalPalace VS Liverpool,"M84X");
    hm.put("CrystalPalace VS ManchesterCity,"M85X");
    hm.put("CrystalPalace VS ManchesterUnited,"M86X");
    hm.put("CrystalPalace VS Middlesbrough,"M87X");
    hm.put("CrystalPalace VS Southampton,"M88X");
    hm.put("CrystalPalace VS Stoke,"M89X");
    hm.put("CrystalPalace VS Sunderland,"M90X");
    hm.put("CrystalPalace VS Swansea,"M91X");
    hm.put("CrystalPalace VS Tottenham,"M92X");
    hm.put("CrystalPalace VS Watford,"M93X");
    hm.put("CrystalPalace VS WestBromWich,"M94X");
    hm.put("CrystalPalace VS WestHam,"M95X");
    hm.put("Everton VS Arsenal,"M96X");
    hm.put("Everton VS Bournemouth,"M97X");
    hm.put("Everton VS Burnley,"M98X");
    hm.put("Everton VS Chelsea,"M99X");
    hm.put("Everton VS CrystalPalace,"M100X");
    hm.put("Everton VS Hull,"M101X");
    hm.put("Everton VS Leicester,"M102X");
    hm.put("Everton VS Liverpool,"M103X");
    hm.put("Everton VS ManchesterCity,"M104X");
    hm.put("Everton VS ManchesterUnited,"M105X");
    hm.put("Everton VS Middlesbrough,"M106X");
    hm.put("Everton VS Southampton,"M107X");
    hm.put("Everton VS Stoke,"M108X");
    hm.put("Everton VS Sunderland,"M109X");
    hm.put("Everton VS Swansea,"M110X");
    hm.put("Everton VS Tottenham,"M111X");
    hm.put("Everton VS Watford,"M112X");
    hm.put("Everton VS WestBromWich,"M113X");
    hm.put("Everton VS WestHam,"M114X");
    hm.put("Hull VS Arsenal,"M115X");
    hm.put("Hull VS Bournemouth,"M116X");
    hm.put("Hull VS Burnley,"M117X");
    hm.put("Hull VS Chelsea,"M118X");
    hm.put("Hull VS CrystalPalace,"M119X");
    hm.put("Hull VS Everton,"M120X");
    hm.put("Hull VS Leicester,"M121X");
    hm.put("Hull VS Liverpool,"M122X");
    hm.put("Hull VS ManchesterCity,"M123X");
    hm.put("Hull VS ManchesterUnited,"M124X");
    hm.put("Hull VS Middlesbrough,"M125X");
    hm.put("Hull VS Southampton,"M126X");
    hm.put("Hull VS Stoke,"M127X");
    hm.put("Hull VS Sunderland,"M128X");
    hm.put("Hull VS Swansea,"M129X");
    hm.put("Hull VS Tottenham,"M130X");
    hm.put("Hull VS Watford,"M131X");
    hm.put("Hull VS WestBromWich,"M132X");
    hm.put("Hull VS WestHam,"M133X");
    hm.put("Leicester VS Arsenal,"M134X");
    hm.put("Leicester VS Bournemouth,"M135X");
    hm.put("Leicester VS Burnley,"M136X");
    hm.put("Leicester VS Chelsea,"M137X");
    hm.put("Leicester VS CrystalPalace,"M138X");
    hm.put("Leicester VS Everton,"M139X");
    hm.put("Leicester VS Hull,"M140X");
    hm.put("Leicester VS Liverpool,"M141X");
    hm.put("Leicester VS ManchesterCity,"M142X");
    hm.put("Leicester VS ManchesterUnited,"M143X");
    hm.put("Leicester VS Middlesbrough,"M144X");
    hm.put("Leicester VS Southampton,"M145X");
    hm.put("Leicester VS Stoke,"M146X");
    hm.put("Leicester VS Sunderland,"M147X");
    hm.put("Leicester VS Swansea,"M148X");
    hm.put("Leicester VS Tottenham,"M149X");
    hm.put("Leicester VS Watford,"M150X");
    hm.put("Leicester VS WestBromWich,"M151X");
    hm.put("Leicester VS WestHam,"M152X");
    hm.put("Liverpool VS Arsenal,"M153X");
    hm.put("Liverpool VS Bournemouth,"M154X");
    hm.put("Liverpool VS Burnley,"M155X");
    hm.put("Liverpool VS Chelsea,"M156X");
    hm.put("Liverpool VS CrystalPalace,"M157X");
    hm.put("Liverpool VS Everton,"M158X");
    hm.put("Liverpool VS Hull,"M159X");
    hm.put("Liverpool VS Leicester,"M160X");
    hm.put("Liverpool VS ManchesterCity,"M161X");
    hm.put("Liverpool VS ManchesterUnited,"M162X");
    hm.put("Liverpool VS Middlesbrough,"M163X");
    hm.put("Liverpool VS Southampton,"M164X");
    hm.put("Liverpool VS Stoke,"M165X");
    hm.put("Liverpool VS Sunderland,"M166X");
    hm.put("Liverpool VS Swansea,"M167X");
    hm.put("Liverpool VS Tottenham,"M168X");
    hm.put("Liverpool VS Watford,"M169X");
    hm.put("Liverpool VS WestBromWich,"M170X");
    hm.put("Liverpool VS WestHam,"M171X");
    hm.put("ManchesterCity VS Arsenal,"M172X");
    hm.put("ManchesterCity VS Bournemouth,"M173X");
    hm.put("ManchesterCity VS Burnley,"M174X");
    hm.put("ManchesterCity VS Chelsea,"M175X");
    hm.put("ManchesterCity VS CrystalPalace,"M176X");
    hm.put("ManchesterCity VS Everton,"M177X");
    hm.put("ManchesterCity VS Hull,"M178X");
    hm.put("ManchesterCity VS Leicester,"M179X");
    hm.put("ManchesterCity VS Liverpool,"M180X");
    hm.put("ManchesterCity VS ManchesterUnited,"M181X");
    hm.put("ManchesterCity VS Middlesbrough,"M182X");
    hm.put("ManchesterCity VS Southampton,"M183X");
    hm.put("ManchesterCity VS Stoke,"M184X");
    hm.put("ManchesterCity VS Sunderland,"M185X");
    hm.put("ManchesterCity VS Swansea,"M186X");
    hm.put("ManchesterCity VS Tottenham,"M187X");
    hm.put("ManchesterCity VS Watford,"M188X");
    hm.put("ManchesterCity VS WestBromWich,"M189X");
    hm.put("ManchesterCity VS WestHam,"M190X");
    hm.put("ManchesterUnited VS Arsenal,"M191X");
    hm.put("ManchesterUnited VS Bournemouth,"M192X");
    hm.put("ManchesterUnited VS Burnley,"M193X");
    hm.put("ManchesterUnited VS Chelsea,"M194X");
    hm.put("ManchesterUnited VS CrystalPalace,"M195X");
    hm.put("ManchesterUnited VS Everton,"M196X");
    hm.put("ManchesterUnited VS Hull,"M197X");
    hm.put("ManchesterUnited VS Leicester,"M198X");
    hm.put("ManchesterUnited VS Liverpool,"M199X");
    hm.put("ManchesterUnited VS ManchesterCity,"M200X");
    hm.put("ManchesterUnited VS Middlesbrough,"M201X");
    hm.put("ManchesterUnited VS Southampton,"M202X");
    hm.put("ManchesterUnited VS Stoke,"M203X");
    hm.put("ManchesterUnited VS Sunderland,"M204X");
    hm.put("ManchesterUnited VS Swansea,"M205X");
    hm.put("ManchesterUnited VS Tottenham,"M206X");
    hm.put("ManchesterUnited VS Watford,"M207X");
    hm.put("ManchesterUnited VS WestBromWich,"M208X");
    hm.put("ManchesterUnited VS WestHam,"M209X");
    hm.put("Middlesbrough VS Arsenal,"M210X");
    hm.put("Middlesbrough VS Bournemouth,"M211X");
    hm.put("Middlesbrough VS Burnley,"M212X");
    hm.put("Middlesbrough VS Chelsea,"M213X");
    hm.put("Middlesbrough VS CrystalPalace,"M214X");
    hm.put("Middlesbrough VS Everton,"M215X");
    hm.put("Middlesbrough VS Hull,"M216X");
    hm.put("Middlesbrough VS Leicester,"M217X");
    hm.put("Middlesbrough VS Liverpool,"M218X");
    hm.put("Middlesbrough VS ManchesterCity,"M219X");
    hm.put("Middlesbrough VS ManchesterUnited,"M220X");
    hm.put("Middlesbrough VS Southampton,"M221X");
    hm.put("Middlesbrough VS Stoke,"M222X");
    hm.put("Middlesbrough VS Sunderland,"M223X");
    hm.put("Middlesbrough VS Swansea,"M224X");
    hm.put("Middlesbrough VS Tottenham,"M225X");
    hm.put("Middlesbrough VS Watford,"M226X");
    hm.put("Middlesbrough VS WestBromWich,"M227X");
    hm.put("Middlesbrough VS WestHam,"M228X");
    hm.put("Southampton VS Arsenal,"M229X");
    hm.put("Southampton VS Bournemouth,"M230X");
    hm.put("Southampton VS Burnley,"M231X");
    hm.put("Southampton VS Chelsea,"M232X");
    hm.put("Southampton VS CrystalPalace,"M233X");
    hm.put("Southampton VS Everton,"M234X");
    hm.put("Southampton VS Hull,"M235X");
    hm.put("Southampton VS Leicester,"M236X");
    hm.put("Southampton VS Liverpool,"M237X");
    hm.put("Southampton VS ManchesterCity,"M238X");
    hm.put("Southampton VS ManchesterUnited,"M239X");
    hm.put("Southampton VS Middlesbrough,"M240X");
    hm.put("Southampton VS Stoke,"M241X");
    hm.put("Southampton VS Sunderland,"M242X");
    hm.put("Southampton VS Swansea,"M243X");
    hm.put("Southampton VS Tottenham,"M244X");
    hm.put("Southampton VS Watford,"M245X");
    hm.put("Southampton VS WestBromWich,"M246X");
    hm.put("Southampton VS WestHam,"M247X");
    hm.put("Stoke VS Arsenal,"M248X");
    hm.put("Stoke VS Bournemouth,"M249X");
    hm.put("Stoke VS Burnley,"M250X");
    hm.put("Stoke VS Chelsea,"M251X");
    hm.put("Stoke VS CrystalPalace,"M252X");
    hm.put("Stoke VS Everton,"M253X");
    hm.put("Stoke VS Hull,"M254X");
    hm.put("Stoke VS Leicester,"M255X");
    hm.put("Stoke VS Liverpool,"M256X");
    hm.put("Stoke VS ManchesterCity,"M257X");
    hm.put("Stoke VS ManchesterUnited,"M258X");
    hm.put("Stoke VS Middlesbrough,"M259X");
    hm.put("Stoke VS Southampton,"M260X");
    hm.put("Stoke VS Sunderland,"M261X");
    hm.put("Stoke VS Swansea,"M262X");
    hm.put("Stoke VS Tottenham,"M263X");
    hm.put("Stoke VS Watford,"M264X");
    hm.put("Stoke VS WestBromWich,"M265X");
    hm.put("Stoke VS WestHam,"M266X");
    hm.put("Sunderland VS Arsenal,"M267X");
    hm.put("Sunderland VS Bournemouth,"M268X");
    hm.put("Sunderland VS Burnley,"M269X");
    hm.put("Sunderland VS Chelsea,"M270X");
    hm.put("Sunderland VS CrystalPalace,"M271X");
    hm.put("Sunderland VS Everton,"M272X");
    hm.put("Sunderland VS Hull,"M273X");
    hm.put("Sunderland VS Leicester,"M274X");
    hm.put("Sunderland VS Liverpool,"M275X");
    hm.put("Sunderland VS ManchesterCity,"M276X");
    hm.put("Sunderland VS ManchesterUnited,"M277X");
    hm.put("Sunderland VS Middlesbrough,"M278X");
    hm.put("Sunderland VS Southampton,"M279X");
    hm.put("Sunderland VS Stoke,"M280X");
    hm.put("Sunderland VS Swansea,"M281X");
    hm.put("Sunderland VS Tottenham,"M282X");
    hm.put("Sunderland VS Watford,"M283X");
    hm.put("Sunderland VS WestBromWich,"M284X");
    hm.put("Sunderland VS WestHam,"M285X");
    hm.put("Swansea VS Arsenal,"M286X");
    hm.put("Swansea VS Bournemouth,"M287X");
    hm.put("Swansea VS Burnley,"M288X");
    hm.put("Swansea VS Chelsea,"M289X");
    hm.put("Swansea VS CrystalPalace,"M290X");
    hm.put("Swansea VS Everton,"M291X");
    hm.put("Swansea VS Hull,"M292X");
    hm.put("Swansea VS Leicester,"M293X");
    hm.put("Swansea VS Liverpool,"M294X");
    hm.put("Swansea VS ManchesterCity,"M295X");
    hm.put("Swansea VS ManchesterUnited,"M296X");
    hm.put("Swansea VS Middlesbrough,"M297X");
    hm.put("Swansea VS Southampton,"M298X");
    hm.put("Swansea VS Stoke,"M299X");
    hm.put("Swansea VS Sunderland,"M300X");
    hm.put("Swansea VS Tottenham,"M301X");
    hm.put("Swansea VS Watford,"M302X");
    hm.put("Swansea VS WestBromWich,"M303X");
    hm.put("Swansea VS WestHam,"M304X");
    hm.put("Tottenham VS Arsenal,"M305X");
    hm.put("Tottenham VS Bournemouth,"M306X");
    hm.put("Tottenham VS Burnley,"M307X");
    hm.put("Tottenham VS Chelsea,"M308X");
    hm.put("Tottenham VS CrystalPalace,"M309X");
    hm.put("Tottenham VS Everton,"M310X");
    hm.put("Tottenham VS Hull,"M311X");
    hm.put("Tottenham VS Leicester,"M312X");
    hm.put("Tottenham VS Liverpool,"M313X");
    hm.put("Tottenham VS ManchesterCity,"M314X");
    hm.put("Tottenham VS ManchesterUnited,"M315X");
    hm.put("Tottenham VS Middlesbrough,"M316X");
    hm.put("Tottenham VS Southampton,"M317X");
    hm.put("Tottenham VS Stoke,"M318X");
    hm.put("Tottenham VS Sunderland,"M319X");
    hm.put("Tottenham VS Swansea,"M320X");
    hm.put("Tottenham VS Watford,"M321X");
    hm.put("Tottenham VS WestBromWich,"M322X");
    hm.put("Tottenham VS WestHam,"M323X");
    hm.put("Watford VS Arsenal,"M324X");
    hm.put("Watford VS Bournemouth,"M325X");
    hm.put("Watford VS Burnley,"M326X");
    hm.put("Watford VS Chelsea,"M327X");
    hm.put("Watford VS CrystalPalace,"M328X");
    hm.put("Watford VS Everton,"M329X");
    hm.put("Watford VS Hull,"M330X");
    hm.put("Watford VS Leicester,"M331X");
    hm.put("Watford VS Liverpool,"M332X");
    hm.put("Watford VS ManchesterCity,"M333X");
    hm.put("Watford VS ManchesterUnited,"M334X");
    hm.put("Watford VS Middlesbrough,"M335X");
    hm.put("Watford VS Southampton,"M336X");
    hm.put("Watford VS Stoke,"M337X");
    hm.put("Watford VS Sunderland,"M338X");
    hm.put("Watford VS Swansea,"M339X");
    hm.put("Watford VS Tottenham,"M340X");
    hm.put("Watford VS WestBromWich,"M341X");
    hm.put("Watford VS WestHam,"M342X");
    hm.put("WestBromWich VS Arsenal,"M343X");
    hm.put("WestBromWich VS Bournemouth,"M344X");
    hm.put("WestBromWich VS Burnley,"M345X");
    hm.put("WestBromWich VS Chelsea,"M346X");
    hm.put("WestBromWich VS CrystalPalace,"M347X");
    hm.put("WestBromWich VS Everton,"M348X");
    hm.put("WestBromWich VS Hull,"M349X");
    hm.put("WestBromWich VS Leicester,"M350X");
    hm.put("WestBromWich VS Liverpool,"M351X");
    hm.put("WestBromWich VS ManchesterCity,"M352X");
    hm.put("WestBromWich VS ManchesterUnited,"M353X");
    hm.put("WestBromWich VS Middlesbrough,"M354X");
    hm.put("WestBromWich VS Southampton,"M355X");
    hm.put("WestBromWich VS Stoke,"M356X");
    hm.put("WestBromWich VS Sunderland,"M357X");
    hm.put("WestBromWich VS Swansea,"M358X");
    hm.put("WestBromWich VS Tottenham,"M359X");
    hm.put("WestBromWich VS Watford,"M360X");
    hm.put("WestBromWich VS WestHam,"M361X");
    hm.put("WestHam VS Arsenal,"M362X");
    hm.put("WestHam VS Bournemouth,"M363X");
    hm.put("WestHam VS Burnley,"M364X");
    hm.put("WestHam VS Chelsea,"M365X");
    hm.put("WestHam VS CrystalPalace,"M366X");
    hm.put("WestHam VS Everton,"M367X");
    hm.put("WestHam VS Hull,"M368X");
    hm.put("WestHam VS Leicester,"M369X");
    hm.put("WestHam VS Liverpool,"M370X");
    hm.put("WestHam VS ManchesterCity,"M371X");
    hm.put("WestHam VS ManchesterUnited,"M372X");
    hm.put("WestHam VS Middlesbrough,"M373X");
    hm.put("WestHam VS Southampton,"M374X");
    hm.put("WestHam VS Stoke,"M375X");
    hm.put("WestHam VS Sunderland,"M376X");
    hm.put("WestHam VS Swansea,"M377X");
    hm.put("WestHam VS Tottenham,"M378X");
    hm.put("WestHam VS Watford,"M379X");
    hm.put("WestHam VS WestBromWich,"M380X");

}
```

Is the size the issue here? What's the best way to fix this?

Comment: First of all, you definitely shouldn't put that into your code. Create a CSV file with any delimiter you want and place it into resources raw folder. Then when the app starts, load that file and write data to a hash map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong with it,

You have an error in your syntax. You missed a `"` before the `,`

Change,

```
hm.put("Arsenal VS Bournemouth,"M1X");
```

to

```
hm.put("Arsenal VS Bournemouth", "M1X");
```

**Edit in all lines.**

But a better approach would be to save the data as a `JSON` file or `CSV` file and then initialize it at runtime as Victor K suggested.

Comment: Oh , I didn't see that crawling in , I programatically generated that much lines, let me see , if it does fix :)

Comment: So, your IDE crashes with a stackoverflow exception while trying to parse your wrongly written code.  Nice.  Time to find a better IDE.